# A JS-based WYSIWYG HTML editor with flexible image upload?

Tags: html, javascript

Is there a good JS-based WYSIWYG HTML editor with flexible image upload out there? Ideally, I'd like an editor that allows me to handle image upload in a custom callback.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is what you're looking for. I haven't used it for a couple of years but it looks like it's still possible (with or without plugins). Also check out their [Docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/).